# Would believers, saints, the church take part in the great tribulation

Tags: matthew

Jesus Matthew 24:37-38
Men 1st thessalonia 4:16-17
Is their anything as secret taking away or we will all face it then at the end christ appears

Comment: The saints who passed away before the last 3 1/2 years won't face the last 3 1/2 years

Comment: Where do you find that in the Bible, @WalterSmetana ?

Comment: 1 Thes 4:16; 1 Cor 15:23, 51-52; 2 Tim 2:18; Dan 12:13; Philip 3:11; Rv 6:9-11; 12:2, 5-6, 9--13:1; 14:13-20; 19:14; 17:14; 20:4. If you want, here or in chat, please feel welcome to provide for me any Scriptures that you know which would indicate that saints who've died, gone to be with the Lord (2 Tim 4:6; 2 Cor 5:8), such as Paul, C.S. Lewis, or ones you know personally (and beside Moses, Mt 17:3; Rv 11:3-15), will resurrect to live on earth for the last 3 1/2 years of this age before Christ touches down on Mount Olives. I would've thought that'd be a more obscure position than mine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Of course we, Christians, will face it!

There is no way that we do not undergo the same what our Lord has undergone - the suffering and death, the cross; for otherwise, unless we participate in His death, we won't participate in His resurrection either (cf. Romans 6:5).

Yes, we, Christians, will face all tribulations (including the last great one of the history of mankind, which is only a particular case of tribulations, not different from them in essence), and we shall enter in them, unavoidably, but we shall not enter into temptation, that is to say, into sin, if we hold and abide with Christ.

All will face death, the illnesses that lead to it, which is highest degree of any tribulation possible, there is no way to avoid those tribulations even for the greatest of saints, but saints undergo those tribulations with hope, strengthened by Christ, with faith and assuredness based on divine revelation that all whom we love will live in Christ's Kingdom together with us in unbreakable bliss, whereas the unbelievers undergo the same differently, without this hope and strength, in despair that they will disappear.

Thus, St Peter far from assuring the believers that they will be exempted in some magic way from tribulations, even praises tribulations and tests as an occasion for spiritual growth of Christians (1 Peter 1:3-9).

Answer (score 0):

The other consideration is, how would we avoid it?  If Christians are not going to be here for the "Great Tribulation", then I suspect it's because they've all gone to "be with Christ in the air."  Which probably means they've all been slaughtered, en masse.  No magical thinking there, and perfectly in context with the situation of the early church.

God does plenty of things in secret, but rescuing his people (more specifically, his "remnant" - Noah, Lot, those who returned from exile...) is not done by secret or supernatural means in any case I can think of.  The exodous was supernatural, but it wasn't secret and it involved plenty of suffering for the "rescued"!  The supernatural preservation stories (Shadrach et al, Daniel...) are not stories of one man (or group) escaping the judgment of God, they're stories of one man (or group) escaping the judgment of another man.  The "Great Tribulation", if that does indeed refer to a particular event sometime in the future (which is debatable), is expected to be a judgment from God.